# Jquery mouseenter and mouseout

Tags: jquery, mouseevent

I have a div (div1) that warps a literal.
on mouseenter I put another div (div2) in front of div1 and on mouseout I hide div2.
my problem is that on mouseenter or hover, its flashing.

this is my code

```
        $(".EditText").mouseenter(function () {
            debugger;
            $("#divEdit").css("display", "block");
            $("#divEdit").css("height", $(this).height() );
            $("#divEdit").css("width", $(this).width() );
            $("#divEdit").css({ "position": "absolute", "top": $(this).offset().top, "left": $(this).offset().left });
        }).mouseout(function () {
            $("#divEdit").css("display", "none");
        });
    });
```

Comment: what do you mean by flashing?

Comment: Please provide some more of your existent code, as it is hard for us guessing what you do.

Comment: If you dynamically place items under the mouse you will trigger `mouseOut` events on some (all?) browsers as it *has* effectively left the previous DIV and entered the child.

Answer (score 0):

If you dynamically place items under the mouse you will trigger `mouseOut` events on some (all?) browsers as it *has* effectively left the previous DIV and entered the child.

You can make the div added transparent to the mouse using a pointer-events style on the added element https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events:

```
style="pointer-events: none;"
```

Note: this does not work on really old browsers.